# Why does my oscilloscope work even without the ground connected to the circuit?

Tags: oscillator, oscilloscope

I am using an oscillator to produce a sinusoidal signal of around 100kHz. I am using a Hantek PC oscilloscope for testing. I observed that even though I disconnect the oscilloscope ground from my circuit, the signal remains the same. How is that possible?

Any idea?

Comment: Is there a path through the mains ground of the scope and the circuit power supply?

Comment: Yes. Now got it. The oscilloscope is connected to my PC USB. And the STM32 board too is powered from USB only. So I think  this makes it common ground.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit must have some other path for the connection.

For example circuit power supply can be connected to PC ground via grounded mains plug, and the PC oscilloscope ground is connected to PC ground.

Comment: Yes. Now got it. The oscilloscope is connected to my PC USB. And the STM32 board too is powered from USB only. So I think  this makes it common ground.

Comment: Yes, that is how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is likely some other path to ground. Most likely through the scope power plug, and from there through a bench top power supply, computer USB connection, etc.